# Spring JavaMailSenderImpl logs into SMTP server every time for sending emails, causing latency in web application

Tags: spring, jakarta-mail

I am using Google's SMTP server to send transactional emails from my web application, using Spring's JavaMailSenderImpl class.
The problem is: the send Email function send(SimpleMailMessage simpleMessage), is authenticating on the SMTP for every email. This is slowing down the web server, as I am sending the emails synchronously (which is of course a bad idea, I should rather be sending the emails asynchronously using a queue.)
Nevertheless my question is:
**Is there a way to save the SMTP auhenitcation during the first email and use it for all the subsequent emails.**

Comment: @Alexandre Cartapanis: Your solution works.

Answer (score 1):

Use the method `send(SimpleMailMessage[] messages)` of JavaMailSenderImpl. It will reuse the same transport for each message.